# Accessibility Issue with HAProxy Load Balancer, VIP, and Keepalived Setup

Tags: haproxy, keepalived

I'm using 2 HAProxy servers with a Virtual IP (VIP) and Keepalived. While I can access the active HAProxy1 server, I face accessibility problems when HAProxy2 is active. How can I resolve the access issue when HAProxy2 is active?

I've configured a setup with a VIP and Keepalived, and generally, I can effectively use the HAProxy load balancer. However, I encounter an access issue when HAProxy2 is active. How can Keepalived affect this situation, or how can I identify a potential issue in the HAProxy configuration?

What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, or pinpoint the source of the problem? I appreciate any guidance you can provide.

HAProxy1 -2 conf:

```
global
    maxconn 100
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    retries 2
    timeout client 30m
    timeout connect 4s
    timeout server 30m
    timeout check 5s

listen stats
   mode http
   bind *:7000
   stats enable
   stats uri /

frontend a_listen_fe
bind *:5911
acl is-read-service-dead nbsrv(standby) lt 1
use_backend postgres if is-read-service-dead
default_backend standby


listen postgres
       bind 10.5.70.190:5000
       option httpchk
       http-check expect status 200
       default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
       server node1 10.5.70.193:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008
       server node2 10.5.70.194:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008
       server node3 10.5.70.195:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008

 listen standby
       option httpchk OPTIONS/replica
       http-check expect status 200
       default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
       server node1 10.5.70.193:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008
       server node2 10.5.70.194:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008
       server node3 10.5.70.195:5432 maxconn 1000 check port 8008
```

Keepalived.conf

```
 global_defs {
 }
 vrrp_script chk_haproxy { # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
     script "killall -0 haproxy" # widely used idiom
     interval 2 # check every 2 seconds
     weight 2 # add 2 points of prio if OK
 }
 vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    interface ens192
    state MASTER # or "BACKUP" on backup
    priority 101 # 101 on master, 100 on backup
 virtual_router_id 51
 advert_int 1
 authentication {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass 1234
 }
 virtual_ipaddress {
    10.5.70.190/24  label ens192:0
 }

 unicast_src_ip 10.5.70.191     # This node
 unicast_peer {                # Other nodes
    10.5.70.192
 }


 track_script {
    chk_haproxy
 }
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is the issue when HAproxy2 is active?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot access VIP 5000 port from the master server.  [postgres@cbspgmaster log]$ traceroute 10.5.70.190 5000
traceroute to 10.5.70.190 (10.5.70.190), 30 hops max, 5000 byte packets

Comment: Can you do a `ss -tulpn` to check if the port is listening

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).